# sending Emails using codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, email

I'm using the below function for sending emails in my codeigniter project

```
public function sendMail()
{
 $this->load->library('email',array('mail_type'=>'html'));

        $this->email->from('waaanjula@gmail.com',"Anjula");
        //$this->email->to($this->input->post('inputEmail'));
        $this->email->to('waaanjula@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Confirm your Registration');

        $message = "<p> Thank you for Registering with us</p>";
        $message.="<p><a href='http://localhost/Registration/index.php/login/register_user/'>Click here</a> </p>";

        $this->email->message($message);

        if($this->email->send()){
            echo "Email has been successfully send ";
        }else{
            echo "Error sending email";
        }
}
```

And it gives "Email has been successfully send " but I does not receive any mail. Can any one advice on this please.

Comment: I guess you are using localhost right?

Comment: yes. I'm using localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I will not work on localhost, deploy it on a server where smtp is working and test it there.

Another way to send an email from localhost is to use another smtp server but I would recommend to just test `mail()` function of php on server as LOCAL HOST doesn't work..

1) Download `PHPMailer`
2) Extract to folder within you php project and rename it to `phpmailer`
3) Create `gmail-sample.php` and paste the following code:

```
<?php
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------
$mail->Username = "your.username@gmail.com"; // your GMail user name
$mail->Password = "your-gmail-password"; 
$mail->AddAddress("friends.email@domain.com"); // recipients email
$mail->FromName = "your name"; // readable name

$mail->Subject = "Subject title";
$mail->Body    = "Here is the message you want to send to your friend."; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

4) Send mail from Browser (e.g. `http://localhost/your-project/gmail-sample.php`).